# Convert Curl to Restassured

Tags: rest, curl, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a cURL that takes a file checksum and xml along with multiple headers in order to upload an image to a server.
Im not very familiar with RestAssured so my question is;
How do i represent the -F cURL values in RestAssured?

```
`curl -s -w "\nHTTP %{http_code}\n" -X POST ${mediaUrl}/api/user/${LCID}/repository/${REPO_NAME}/file?conflictSolve=copy \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.******.dv-1.19+xml" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-H "Authorization: *** token=\"${TOKEN}\"; authVersion=\"1.0\"" \
-H "x-******-***: ${TOKEN}" \
-H "X-Client-Identifier: TEST" \
-H "X-Client-Platform: CURL" \
-H "x-ingest-tag:RI" \
-F "files=@${XML};type=application/vnd.******.dv-1.19+xml" \
-F "${checksum}=@${file};type=${mimeType}"`
```

Currently i have progressed with the only the headers.

```
        Response response = given()
            .log().all()

            .spec(RestUtilities.get**RequestSpecification())    
            .header("Accept","application/vnd.******.dv-1.19+xml")
            .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
            .header("Authorization", "*** token=\""+access_token+"\"; authVersion=\"1.0\";")
            .header("x-*****-***", "access_token")

    .when()
        .post()
    .then()
    .log().all()
        .statusCode(200)
        .extract()
        .response();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The property curl [-F](http://%20https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) will produce a request POST with datas using the Content-Type multipart/form-data http header.

So with RestAssured you have to call the method multipart ([see the doc here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#multi-part-form-data)) to upload the file.

Here an example :

```
 @Test
public void postMultipart() throws Exception {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
    File xmlfile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:demo.xml").getFile();
    given()
            .log().all()
            .multiPart("files", xmlfile, "application/xml")
            .when()
            .post("/upload")
            .then()
            .log().all()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract()
            .response();
}
```

So the param 
-F "files=@${XML};type=application/vnd.******.dv-1.19+xml" \

Can be convert to 
.multiPart("files", {YOUR-XML}, "application/vnd.******.dv-1.19+xml")

You can see the full source example [in my Github](https://github.com/bdzzaid/fdm/blob/master/stackoverflow/src/test/java/bdzzaid/stackoverflow/ConvertCurlToRestAssuredTest.java)